# Div already showing before click

Tags: jquery

I have this link

```
   <a href='' style = 'color:black' id = 'compose'>Compose</a>
```

that i would like it to show this div id = '#composemessage' when it is clicked

```
  <div id='buddies-messages' style= 'float:right;width:60%;height:100%;border:1px solid black' >    
    <!--compose message div-->
    <div id = '#composemessage'>
        <form>
          <div><textarea id='post_content' name='post_content' cols = '79' rows = '5'></textarea></div>
         <div style = 'float:right'><input type='submit' id='post' name='post' value='Post Status' /></div>

    </div>
 </div>

   <script>
     $('#compose').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#composemessage').show();
    });
   </script>
```

but the div is already showing even before i clicked the link. What could be the problem?

Comment: is #composemessage display:none; ?

Comment: <div id='#composemessage' style='display:none;'>

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `display:none;` to your div, so it's hidding. You also have to remove the hash in your DOM as **j08691** mentioned

```
  <div id='buddies-messages' style= 'float:right;width:60%;height:100%;border:1px solid black' >    
    <!--compose message div-->
    <div id = 'composemessage' style = 'display:none;'>
        <form>
          <div><textarea id='post_content' name='post_content' cols = '79' rows = '5'></textarea></div>
         <div style = 'float:right'><input type='submit' id='post' name='post' value='Post Status' /></div>

    </div>
 </div>

   <script>
     $('#compose').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#composemessage').show();
    });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're actually hiding the div first, your div's ID is wrong. Remove the `#`.

Use `<div id = 'composemessage'>` not `<div id = '#composemessage'>`.

`#` is the jQuery ID selector.